# Return value if a specific year falls between two dates python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe elec2:

```
    Start_Date  End_Date    
0   2014-05-16  2015-05-18  
1   2015-05-19  2018-05-13  
2   2016-05-14  2017-05-12  
3   2017-05-13  2018-05-16  
4   2018-05-17  2019-05-14
```

Output expected:

```
    Start_Date  End_Date    Value
0   2014-05-16  2017-05-18  0
1   2015-05-19  2018-05-13  1
2   2016-05-14  2017-05-12  0
3   2017-05-13  2018-05-16  1
4   2018-05-17  2019-05-14  0
```

I would like to add 1 if the start_date starts by the year 2017 and if the year 2017 is between start_Date and the End_Date but if the End_date is the year 2017 then it's 0.

I did this and it's working for the first condition but I don't know how to do for the others.

```
elec2["Value"]=elec2.apply(lambda x: 1 if (x["Start_Date"].year==2017)
                        else
                        0,axis=1)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think, you can take "Start_Date" and "End_Date"s first 4 character and parse them to as Int to series. Then you can add value column to data frame by comparing startYear<2017 and EndYear>2017 is 1 and other's as 0s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly different to @jezrael his answer:

```
df['Value'] = ((pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Start_Date']).year <= 2017) & (pd.DatetimeIndex(df['End_Date']).year > 2017))*1
```

Or when your `DataFrame` is already a `DateTime` object:

```
df['Value'] = ((df.iloc[:, 0].dt.year <= 2017) & (df.iloc[:, 1].dt.year > 2017))*1
```

You can also use `.astype(int)` instead of `*1`

I'm still getting the hang of things within Python, and the above can probably be done more Pythonic...

Answer (score 4):

First convert columns to DataFrames, convert to years by [`Series.dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) and compare by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for equal, [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) for greater, [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) for less and [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) for not equal:

```
df['Start_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_Date'])
df['End_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End_Date'])

s = df['Start_Date'].dt.year
e = df['End_Date'].dt.year

m1 = s.eq(2017)
m2 = s.lt(2017) & e.gt(2017)
m3 = e.ne(2017)
```

Last chain all masks together `m1` and `m2` with bitwise `OR` (`|`) and `m3` chained by bitwise `AND` by `&` and last convert to integers by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) or [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html):

```
df['Value'] =  ((m1 | m2) & m3).astype(int)
#alternative
#df['Value'] =  ((m1 | m2) & m3).view('i1')
print (df)
  Start_Date   End_Date  Value
0 2014-05-16 2015-05-18      0
1 2015-05-19 2018-05-13      1
2 2016-05-14 2017-05-12      0
3 2017-05-13 2018-05-16      1
4 2018-05-17 2019-05-14      0
```

Comment: You and a few others on here just amaze me each time with the speed and knowhow on Python related questions. Keep up the good work.